# Get Android not-debuggable app's databases folder without root privilege

Tags: android, adb

With root privilege, we can get `databases` by:

```
adb pull data/data/app.id/databases
```

If the app is debuggable, we can get `databases` using `run-as` command.

---

However, for a not-debuggable android app, is there still any way to get its `databases` folder, without root privilege (Android 13)?

Existing answers are either...

- not for latest Android OS (deprecated)
- require root privilege
- require app to be debuggable

Use case: forensic data acquisition

Comment: The `adb pull` command does not work if the phone is rooted, only if adb is also running in root mode this works.

Comment: On older Android versions (pre v12) `adb backup` was option if the app had not disallowed backup. But on recent Android versions the app-private folders are really private: only the app itself has access. So as long as you don't have an root exploit you can not access the contained files.

Comment: @Robert I heard some commercial software like Cellebrite UFED has sth called "apk downgrade". It works by downgrading the apk version, and the app need to move the data out, and move in after re-installing. And by that action, it can retrieve the data... not sure whether that will work since I currently don't have access to it...

Comment: Most likely that process involved `adb backup`. Often older versions of an app allow backup, therefore you can uninstall the app but keep the app data, install the old version, perform `adb backup` and extract the data from the backup file. However I am not sure if this still works as `adb backup` has changed it's behavior since Android 12.

Comment: @Robert I tried `adb backup` and the `databases` folder is not in the result. If apk downgrade is based on such feature, I don't think it should be working.

Comment: Some recent updates: I tried Cellebrite UFED's "apk downgrade", and it actually worked. However, since it's closed-sourced commercial software, I've got no idea how it works in detail.